# How to post an jpeg image to Facebook me/staging_resources?

Tags: facebook, image, http, post

I'm trying to upload a jpeg image to me/staging_resources by doing something similar to what curl does:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources \
  -F "file=@images/prawn-curry-1.jpg" \
  -F "access_token=$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

The above is from Facebook doc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/#staging).

My HTTP request looks something like this:

> METHOD: POST
>
> HEADERS:
>
> Content-Type    multipart/form-data;boundary=Random_Boundary_Chars
>
> BODY:
>
> ```
> --Random_Boundary_Chars
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="access_token"
>
> USER_AUTH_TOKEN
>
> --Random_Boundary_Chars
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> ```
>
> 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
>
> ```
> --Random_Boundary_Chars--
> ```

The problem is I'm always getting this response from the server:

> "WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types: image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" ".

In what format should I attach the image to the HTTP request? (I've tried encoding it base64 and also tried using an URL encoder).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It seems the image can be sent as a binary data so no encoding is really needed. The only thing that Facebook is actually checking is the filename attribute that must have a correct extension. So this will translate into:

```
--Random_Boundary_Chars
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="randomName.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

JPEG_BINARY_DATA
--Random_Boundary_Chars--
```